# why my website isn't recognised by google?

Tags: html, google, pagerank, google-ranking

i have a big problem. My website is invisible by google. Why ?

i have made my robots.txt and sitemap.xml and all looks pretty good.

my website : (removed; potentially spam)

thanks à lot

Forthomme Fabian

Comment: When did you first put up your site?  Also, can you provide the contents of your `robots.txt` file?

Comment: sure it's picked up by google, you're at the 10th place if you search for 'record huy banque crédits placements'. Not a good result though, but there may be many reasons for that (no incoming links, only recently online, not many content changes, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Sign up for [Google's WebmasterTools](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=sitemaps&passive=1209600&continue=https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/&followup=https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) to see if there are any problems.

Also try to search @ google for:

site:recordhuy.be

to find out if you really aren't indexed or you just have bad SEO.

**UPDATE**

Yup your site is [indexed](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site%3Arecordhuy.be#sclient=psy-ab&hl=nl&source=hp&q=site%3arecordhuy.be&pbx=1&oq=site%3arecordhuy.be&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2994l2994l2l3156l1l0l1l0l0l0l0l0ll1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=eabe8a0111a1622d&biw=1366&bih=667) just fine.